# how many comparisons would occur in an array of 16 elements during insertion sort?

Tags: sorting, insertion

I'm trying to understand how many comparisons would occur in total when we are trying to implement insertion sort. i know that how it works is it compares first 2 number, then first three and so on. How would the number of comparisons differ when this array is in order and reverse order?

Comment: Why not trace out the flow of the algorithm on paper for progressively larger sets to help yourself understand it and visualize the results? I bet you'll have figured out how it scales long before you get to sixteen.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort - see the box at the upper right with the graphic representation, and read the text below that image.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a worst case order, the number of compares on each step is 1, 2, 3, ... n-1, and the total number of compares is (n-1)(n)/2 = (n^2 - n)/2.